# Rcpp functions undefined when used alongside Stan

Tags: r, rcpp, stan, rstan

I have an R package that uses **Rcpp** for some internal functions. These functions are not exported for the user to access directly (see minimally reproducible example in the [rcpptest](https://github.com/wjakethompson/rcpptest) repository).

I am now attempting to add *Stan* code to the `src/` directory to be compiled when the package is installed (reproducible example in the [rcppstan](https://github.com/wjakethompson/rcppstan) repository). However, when I modify the package to work with Stan, I get the following error in R CMD CHECK:

```
#> ❯ checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
#>   meanC: no visible binding for global variable ‘_rcppstan_meanC’
#>   Undefined global functions or variables:
#>     _rcppstan_meanC
```

And indeed, when I try to call the R function that uses the `meanC` function, I get an error saying `Error in meanC(x) : object '_rcppstan_meanC' not found`.

From what I can tell, here is what is changing when I modify the package to work with **rstan**, and thus the likely cause.

1. When only using **Rcpp**, the following is in the `src/RcppExports.cpp`:

   ```cs
   static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
       {"_rcpptest_timesTwo", (DL_FUNC) &_rcpptest_timesTwo, 1},
       {NULL, NULL, 0}
   };

   RcppExport void R_init_rcpptest(DllInfo *dll) {
       R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
       R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
   }
   ```
2. When *Stan* is incorporated, that code is no longer generated in the `src/RcppExports.cpp` file. Instead, it appears that this is being handles by the `src/init.cpp` file created by the **rstantools** package. The relevant chunk from that file is here:

   ```cs
   static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
     {NULL, NULL, 0}
   };

   void attribute_visible R_init_rcppstan(DllInfo *dll) {
     // next line is necessary to avoid a NOTE from R CMD check
     R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
     R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, TRUE); // necessary for .onLoad() to work
   }
   ```

Why does the code in `src/init.cpp` make the **Rcpp** functions undefined? Conversely, is there a way to edit `src/init.cpp` so that the *Stan* models are able to compile and be accessed correctly, while still allowing the **Rcpp** functions to be defined?

Comment: When we wrote `rstantools::rstan_package_skeleton`, we never considered the case where someone would have other compiled code besides the C++ representation of Stan programs. What happens if you just delete `src/init.cpp`? It does not serve much purpose in a Stan-based package, but it avoids a warning from `R CMD check` about there being C++ code but registration. You may have to change `R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);` to `R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, TRUE);` in `src/RcppExports.cpp`.

Comment: When I remove `src/init.cpp` the package fails to build:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'init.o', needed by 'rcppstan.so'.  Stop.
rm stan_files/uni_irt.cc
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rcppstan’`

It appears that `init.o` is referenced in `src/Makevars` that is generated by `rstantools::rstan_package_skeleton`

Comment: In addition, please see the 10+ other packages that are shown as having a reverse `LinkTo` dependency on rstan: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/

Comment: @coatless there are two links. The first goes to a package with only Rcpp (rcpptest), the second to a package with Rcpp and rstan (rcppstan). Both are included to illustrate the problem that occurs accessing the Rcpp functions when rstan is added. Additionally, the problem isn't with rstan specifically (I have written other packages that depend on rstan just fine), but rather having both rstan and Rcpp. Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: @JakeThompson Try changing the line in `src/Makevars{.win}` from `OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.stan=.o) init.o` to just `OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.stan=.o)`.

Comment: @BenGoodrich This fixed the package build problem, but introduced new errors related to the registering of routines. I have migrated to here: http://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/compiled-code-from-stan-and-rcpp/4429 to better describe what is now happening.

Answer (score 1):

The `init.cpp` takes of registering methods and `Makevars` inhibits compilation of the `cpp` files. With the following changes in `Makevars` (and `Makevars.win`) I got it to compile:

```
diff --git a/src/Makevars b/src/Makevars
index 7aedc5b..3ea312e 100644
--- a/src/Makevars
+++ b/src/Makevars
@@ -1,8 +1,9 @@
 STANHEADERS_SRC = `"$(R_HOME)/bin$(R_ARCH_BIN)/Rscript" --vanilla -e "cat(system.file('include', 'src', package = 'StanHeaders'))"`
 PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I"../inst/include" -I"$(STANHEADERS_SRC)" -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -DBOOST_MATH_OVERFLOW_ERROR_POLICY=errno_on_error

-SOURCES = $(wildcard stan_files/*.stan)
-OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.stan=.o) init.o
+CPP_SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
+STAN_SOURCES = $(wildcard stan_files/*.stan)
+OBJECTS = $(STAN_SOURCES:.stan=.o) $(CPP_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

 all: $(SHLIB)
                @if test -e "/usr/bin/install_name_tool" && test -e "/usr/local/clang4/lib/libc++.1.dylib" && test -e "/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib"; then /usr/bin/install_name_tool -change /usr/local/clang4/lib/libc++.1.dylib /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib $(SHLIB); fi
```

After calling `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` the method registration was again present in `RcppExports.cpp`. When I tried `R CMD INSTALL`, I got an error from `.onLoad()`, c.f. https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/issues/190. Using the workaround from there, i.e. `R CMD INSTALL --preclean` solved the issue first, but was not reliable. What solved the issue for me was to change

```
R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
```

into

```
R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, TRUE);
```

in `RcppExports.cpp`. That is of course problematic, since that file might be overwritten, in particular when RStudio/devtools is used. A rather hacky solution would be to add

```
RcppExports.o: patch

patch:
        sed -i 's/R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE)/R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, TRUE)/' RcppExports.cpp

.phony: all clean patch
```

in the `Makevars(.win)`. But in the end the problem seems to be that C++ code for Rcpp modules is generated during package installation in a subdirectory of `src`. Therefore `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` cannot include the corresponding methofs in the list of registered methods. I do not see a good solution for that. 
Now the package builds, checks and installs with two NOTEs:

```
N  checking installed package size
   installed size is  7.8Mb
   sub-directories of 1Mb or more:
     libs   7.7Mb
N  checking for GNU extensions in Makefiles
   GNU make is a SystemRequirements.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Unfortunately, the `.onLoad()` function is required by packages that interface with Stan in order to be able to access the Stan models from other functions.

Comment: If you add `GNUmake` to `SystemRequirements:` in `DESCRIPTION` the 2nd NOTE should go away.

Comment: @Dirk the `DESCRIPTION` already contains `SystemRequirements: GNU make`. If I remove the space, I get a WARNING because of GNU make extensions. It seems this NOTE is the best one can do.

Comment: Ah, yes, maybe.  It has been a while since I needed it.